# Creating a view query and can't specify attributes

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to create a view query which shows `TITLE_NAME` amongst the other attributes. The `STAFF` records each have a `TITLE_ID` value, so I need to find a way of getting the `TITLE_NAME` value that matches each of these records over from the `TITLE_LOOK_UP` table to show in the view, without seeing the `TITLE_ID`.

```
SELECT
      TITLE_LOOK_UP.TITLE_NAME
    , STAFF.FIRST_NAME
    , STAFF.LAST_NAME
    , STAFF.DEPT_ID
  FROM STAFF   
  WHERE STAFF.POST_ID ='2',
    STAFF.TITLE_ID = TITLE_LOOK_UP.TITLE_ID
  ORDER BY STAFF.LAST_NAME ASC
```

That is what I have so far. I think it's something I'm going to have to use a WHERE command for but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think you should use `AND` in between two conditions within `WHERE` clause instead of `,`: `WHERE STAFF.POST_ID ='2' AND STAFF.TITLE_ID = TITLE_LOOK_UP.TITLE_ID`.

Comment: Aah yes. That is true but unfortunately hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a query using Oracle inner join syntax:

```
SELECT
      TITLE_LOOK_UP.TITLE_NAME
    , STAFF.FIRST_NAME
    , STAFF.LAST_NAME
    , STAFF.DEPT_ID
  FROM STAFF, TITLE_LOOK_UP
  WHERE STAFF.POST_ID ='2' AND
    STAFF.TITLE_ID = TITLE_LOOK_UP.TITLE_ID
  ORDER BY STAFF.LAST_NAME ASC
```